# Generating fatal error in Java

Tags: java, exception

Suppose we are writing a Java library, which provides some I/O ulitity functions, for example, a convenient method to read text files as Strings:

```
public class StringReader {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLog(StringReader.class);

/**
 * Returns the contents of file <b>fileName</b> as String.
 * @param fileName file name to read
 * @return null on IO error
 */
public static String readString(String fileName) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(data);
        return new String(data, "ISO-8859-1"); // may throw UnsupportedEncodingException!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("unable to read file", e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.fatal("JRE does not support ISO-8859-1!", e);
        // ???
    } finally {
        closeQuiet(fis);
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

This code reads a text file into a String using ISO-8859-1 encoding and returns the String to user.

The `String(byte[], String)` constructor throws an `UnsupportedEncodingException` when specified encoding is not supported. But, as we know, `ISO-8859-1` must be supported by JRE, as said [here (see the **Standard charsets** section)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Hence, we expect the block

```
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    log.fatal("encoding is unsupported", e);
    // ???
}
```

is never reached if JRE distribution conforms the standard.

But what if it doesn't? How to handle this exception in the most correct way?
The question is, how to alert properly about such error?

The suggestions are:

1. Throw some kind of `RuntimeException`.
2. Do not disable the logger in production code, write an exception details in log and ignore it.
3. Put the `assert false` here, so it produce AssertionError if user launched VM with `-ea`.
4. Throw an `AssertionError` manually.
5. Add an `UnsupportedEncodingException` in method declaration and allow user to choose. Not very convenient, I think.
6. Call `System.exit(1)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But what if it doesn't?

Then you're in a really bad situation, and you should probably get out of it as quickly as possible. When a JRE is violating its own promises, what *would* you want to depend on?

I'd feel happy using `AssertionError` in this case.

It's important to note that not all unchecked exceptions are treated equally - it's not unusual for code to catch `Exception` at the top level of the stack, log an error and then keep going... if you just throw `RuntimeException`, that *will* be caught by such a scheme. `AssertionError` would only be caught if the catch block specified `Throwable` (or specifically `Error` or `AssertionError`, but that's much rarer to see). Given how impossible this should be, I think it's reasonable to abort really hard.

Also note that in Java 7, you can use `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` instead of the string name, which is cleaner and removes the problem.

There are other things I'd change about your code, by the way:

- I would avoid using `available()` as far as possible. That tells you how many bytes are available *right now* - it doesn't tell you how long the file is, necessarily.
- I would *definitely* not assume that `read()` will read the whole file in one go. Call `read()` in a loop, ideally until it says there's no more data.
- I would personally accept a `Charset` as a parameter, rather than hard-coding ISO-8859-1. - I would let `IOException` bubble up from the method rather than just returning `null`. After all, unless you're *really* going to check the return value of every call for nullity, you're just going to end up with a `NullPointerException` instead, which is harder to diagnose than the original `IOException`.

Alternatively, just use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Files.toString(File, Charset)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to start with :) (If you're not already using Guava, now is a good time to start...)

Comment: I would like to give +1 once for every single paragraph in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a rather common occurrence in code.

Unchecked exceptions are made for this. They shouldn't happen (which is why they are unchecked), but if they do, there is still an exception.

So, throw a `RuntimeException` that has the original `Exception` as the cause.

```
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); //should not happen
}
```

`assert(false);` also throws an unchecked exception, but it assertions can be turned off, so I would recommend RuntimeException.

Comment: `assert(false)` will only throw when assertion checking is turned on though.

Comment: I might have been editing when you made this comment :/ IMO assertions should usually be used for assumptions related debugging, since they can be turned on and off.

Comment: I prefer `AssertionError` over `RuntimeException`. It makes it clearer that this is something you never expect to happen. `RuntimeException` is also sometimes used to wrap other regularly-expected exceptions that can't simply be thrown. Also other people are less likely to catch an `Error` than an `Exception`.

Comment: True, but what if assertions are turned off? Then there is nothing thrown. (Okay, there isn't anything thrown anyway, I know...but it's like not putting it there to begin with.)

Comment: However, if a fatal error is what you want, then you should throw an Error, not an Exception.